# How found offset index a string in rune using go

Tags: string, go, rune

How found offset index a string in []rune using go?

I can do this work with string type.

`if i := strings.Index(input[offset:], "}}"); i > 0 {print(i);}`

but i need for runes.

i have a rune and want get offset index.

how can do this work with runes type in go?

example for more undrestand want need:

```
int offset=0//mean start from 0 (this is important for me)
string text="123456783}}56"
if i := strings.Index(text[offset:], "}}"); i > 0 {print(i);}
```

output of this example is : `9`

but i want do this with []rune type(text variable)

may?

see my current code : https://play.golang.org/p/seImKzVpdh

tank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit #2:** You again indicated a new type "meaning" of your question: you want to search a `string` in a `[]rune`.

Answer: this is not supported directly in the standard library. But it's easy to implement it with 2 `for` loops:

```
func search(text []rune, what string) int {
    whatRunes := []rune(what)

    for i := range text {
        found := true
        for j := range whatRunes {
            if text[i+j] != whatRunes[j] {
                found = false
                break
            }
        }
        if found {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Testing it:

```
value := []rune("123}456}}789")
result := search(value, "}}")
fmt.Println(result)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QcvvHBHmpV)):

```
7
```

---

**Edit:** You updated the question indicating that you want to search `rune`s in a `string`.

You may easily convert a `[]rune` to a `string` using a simple type conversion:

```
toSearchRunes := []rune{'}', '}'}
toSearch := string(toSearchRunes)
```

And from there on, you can use `strings.Index()` as you did in your example:

```
if i := strings.Index(text[offset:], toSearch); i > 0 {
    print(i)
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pDm7G4iw9n).

Original answer follows:

---

`string` values in Go are stored as UTF-8 encoded bytes. [`strings.Index()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Index) returns you the byte position if the given substring is found.

So basically what you want is to convert this byte-position to rune-position. The [`unicode/utf8`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) package contains utility functions for telling the rune-count or rune-length of a `string`: [`utf8.RuneCountInString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#RuneCountInString).

So basically you just need to pass the substring to this function:

```
offset := 0
text := "123456789}}56"
if i := strings.Index(text[offset:], "}}"); i > 0 {
    fmt.Println("byte-pos:", i, "rune-pos:", utf8.RuneCountInString(text[offset:i]))
}

text = "世界}}世界"
if i := strings.Index(text[offset:], "}}"); i > 0 {
    fmt.Println("byte-pos:", i, "rune-pos:", utf8.RuneCountInString(text[offset:i]))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/A1mlDF0M7J)):

```
byte-pos: 9 rune-pos: 9
byte-pos: 6 rune-pos: 2
```

Note: `offset` must also be a byte position, because when slicing a `string` like `text[offset:]`, the index is interpreted as byte-index.

If you want to get the index of a `rune`, use [`strings.IndexRune()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#IndexRune) instead of `strings.Index()`.